# How to gives support of arm64 bit in iOS Project

Tags: ios, xcode, tesseract, arm64

I have implemented [Tesseract-OCR-iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS) into my project. It works nice into my app. But when I gave arm64 bit support into my app, then I can not able to create build of my app.

Here, Following is screenshot of my app's Build Settings of Target without arm64 bit support. And working nice with this:-

[image]

With this settings, I can not able to create build from [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/index.php). Here, I am attaching screenshot diawi site, when I am trying to upload my app's build. but Diawi says only, techical error occured.

[image]

Also, I am attaching screenshot of my app's Build Settings of Target with arm64 bit support.

[image]

when I am trying with this settings, xcode gives following errors into my project.

[image]

I know that, 64-bit is a recommendation. Since not all devices run 64-bit, they must allow 32-bit apps on the App Store. Only when all devices run 64-bit can Apple enforce such a restriction, otherwise all new apps wouldn't work on older devices.

I know how to give support of 64-bit into my project, but there is one or two libraries into Tesseract SDK, and it supports only 32-bit architecture, and when I am trying to giving support of 64-bit, then project gives errors because of that libraries. –

But how can I do this into my project..?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't notice any other *Undefined symbol* questions on the site when you searched?

Comment: I searched a lot, but didn't get any solution, that's why I am posting this.

Comment: Do you understand the problem, at least?

Comment: Yess, I know. The problem is my project didn't support with 64-bit. That's why this all happens.

Comment: No, I don't think you do understand the problem.  Start by studying what *Undefined symbols for...* actually means.

Comment: No.  You research it yourself.

Comment: I know that, there is one or two libraries into Tesseract SDk, and it supports only 32-bit architecture, and when I am trying to giving support of 64-bit, then project gives errors because of that libraries.

Comment: That sounds like a show-stopper to me then.

Comment: Possible reason : Library Tesseract is not compatible to run on simulator, as its not compiled for x86_64 bit architecture. If you try to run on simulator it will not work, you need to run on device only. To support this architecture you need to compile this lib for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the your `Linked Libraries` under `Build phase`.

Go to `Build phases` check for "`Link Binary with Libraries`" , inside which check for the particular `framework` that you are adding.

If in case any of your files are missing then make sure to check "`Compile sources`" and then check for the class `file` and `add` it.

Else if you are using `PODS` then make sure to mention the `pod version` for the `framework` that you are using.